# Does anyone have a good tutorial in nosql with php

Tags: php, nosql

I am trying to get to understand nosql and how to use it with php so if anybody have a link to a tutorial that would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

noSQL now is just a collection of Database that doesn't store relational data.

With the current development of NoSQL, you can pick from the following:

1. CouchDB
2. MongoDB
3. RavenDB
4. SimpleDB

Here are some concept talks here you might want to go through first
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGBH-KfPl_8 (By O'reilly)

---

But in the end, if you are ready to get on this document based database, you are better off with everything Javascript, like Node.JS

Since you asked about PHP. here is one that is okay **after you have grasped** the core concept:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-couchdb/

Comment: NP. We start to plan our transitioning to NoSQL when we realize there are a lot of NULL in our MySQL database and we don't actually update those rows in a matter of years.

Comment: thanks a lot @Peter Du
I heard about NoSQL and thought to ask but my friend didn't explain all of what you have explained to me

thanks a lot i appreciate it